# Regular expression for preg_split() by new line

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

This is my file:

```
0.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 2.0 5.0 2.0 1.0 5.0 5.0 1.0 2.0 7.1 5.0
5.0 0.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 2.0 5.0 1.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 1.0 7.1
5.0 5.0 0.0 6.0 1.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 1.0 6.0 5.0 7.0 1.0 5.0 6.0
6.0 5.0 6.0 0.0 5.0 2.0 1.0 6.0 5.0 6.0 2.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 5.0
7.0 5.0 1.0 5.0 0.0 7.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 5.0 6.0 2.0 2.0 5.0
2.0 2.0 6.0 2.0 7.0 0.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 5.0 2.0 5.0 1.0 2.0 5.0
5.0 5.0 5.0 1.0 1.0 5.0 0.0 2.0 6.0 1.0 5.0 7.0 5.0 1.0 6.0
7.0 1.0 5.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 5.0 6.0 5.0 2.0 6.0 7.0 0.0 5.0
5.0 7.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 2.0 6.0 2.0 1.0 5.0 6.0 5.0 0.0
```

I would split it by \n and have returned in one array each row. How can I do the regular expression?

```
$rows = preg_split('$regular_expression', $content);
```

After I will extract all the rows, how can I extract each value separated by backspace?

```
$values_in_a_row = preg_split('$regular_expression', $a_row);
```

Here the text were I am trying to do it http://regexr.com?2v23c .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't any need for regular expressions:

```
<?php
    $data = explode("\n", $data); // preg_split('#\n#', $data); Please don't
    foreach($data as &$row) {
        $row = explode(' ', $row); // preg_split('#\s#', $row); Seriously
    }
    print_r($data);
?>

<test></test>
```

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker OP shouldn't use regexp in that case

Comment: I wouldn't use regex, you wouldn't. But it's up to OP :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker It's up to me to tell the OP what I think of his use of regexp and make this world a better place.

Comment: Tom, that's why I upvoted you, but you want to be not just right, but also impeccable.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker OP made me go FFFFUUUU, couldn't help it. Edited code's comments for impeccability.

Comment: @michele you don't need a regexp for a single character mask. The explode function is your friend in your case.

Comment: @michele, don't waste computing power, computers are people too.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Now that's a shame. Going to meta right now. Wish I could upvote myself too.

Comment: So who consume less power? regexp or explode?

Comment: Definetely explode ! Preg_split will bring your server's entire neighborhood down ! Talk about 2012 getting close.

Comment: ok, thanks but now i don't know who answer......each user take me a good and correct answer.

Comment: The issue is, what if it isn't using the \n newline character?

Comment: @LiamW Exactly the problem I was having. See my answer

Comment: This does not answer the question. Not all strings use `\n` for newlines.

Comment: it may be overpowered to use a regex, but it is not wrong. your answer might be working in this special case, but i voted down because of three things: 1) it is not even partially an answer to OPs question, 2) you did not explain WHY regular expressions are not the best idea in this case and 3) you didn't even bother to think about the feedback you already got and cared to edit your answer

Answer (score 44):

If you are having issues because you don't know if each newline is just `\n` or `\r\n` or `\r` then none of the above answers work and a regexp works. What I did was

```
$lines = preg_split("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/",$content);
```

Then you can use the accepted answer to split the spaces.

Comment: `$lines = preg_split('~\R~',$content);`

Comment: '~\R~' will break Chinese character 先

Answer (score 6):

```
$rowsapart = preg_split("/\n/",$rowstogether);

$colspart = preg_split("/\s/",$colstogether);
```

Comment: I tested. The link doesn't open well for me, but I'd assume it uses different flavor of regex.

Comment: The problem with this code-only answer is that the OP and researchers may not understand how to set up this technique. In other words, they might not know how to declare `$rowstogether` and `$colstogether`.

Answer (score 2):

No need for REGEX, use `explode()` instead:

```
<?php

    $file = <<<EOF
    0.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 2.0 5.0 2.0 1.0 5.0 5.0 1.0 2.0 7.1 5.0
    5.0 0.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 2.0 5.0 1.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 1.0 7.1
    5.0 5.0 0.0 6.0 1.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 1.0 6.0 5.0 7.0 1.0 5.0 6.0
    6.0 5.0 6.0 0.0 5.0 2.0 1.0 6.0 5.0 6.0 2.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 5.0
    7.0 5.0 1.0 5.0 0.0 7.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 5.0 6.0 2.0 2.0 5.0
    2.0 2.0 6.0 2.0 7.0 0.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 5.0 2.0 5.0 1.0 2.0 5.0
    5.0 5.0 5.0 1.0 1.0 5.0 0.0 2.0 6.0 1.0 5.0 7.0 5.0 1.0 6.0
    7.0 1.0 5.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 5.0 6.0 5.0 2.0 6.0 7.0 0.0 5.0
    5.0 7.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 2.0 6.0 2.0 1.0 5.0 6.0 5.0 0.0
    EOF;

    $rows = explode("\n", $file);
    print_r($rows);
    echo "\n\n"; //Spacing

    $numbers_in_a_row = explode(" ", $rows[0]);
    print_r($numbers_in_a_row);

?>
```

**[Live Example](http://codepad.org/5kdidTWE)**

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_split("/\R/", $content);
```

It is the most reliable way to split text by new lines if you are sure that incoming content has Unicode format.

`/\R/` Matches any Unicode newline sequence that is in the ASCII range. it is equivalent to

```
/(?>\r\n|\n|\r|\f|\x0b|\x85)/
```

Comment: This does not split the rows apart.  You are only solving half of the question.